# Notekeeping tool that doesn't lock you in

Tags: knowledge-management

We all know that having a good note taking tool is important as a developer.

However, OneNote and Evernote forces us to be locked in to a particular vendor.

Anyone know of good open-source tools, or even other method of taking notes w/o being "locked-in"?

EDIT: I should kick myself in the head for not specifying. Taking text notes is easy. I'd love to be able to write ink notes ( I use a tablet ), add images,and sketch GUI ideas.

Comment: I just don't get the whole "fear of lock-in". You're always locked into SOMETHING every time you use software. IMHO, get over it. If the app solves your problem, stop whining about lock-in.

Comment: How is open source not "locked in"?

Comment: @DOK In general, if something is open (source) you are not locked into a proprietary software and its standards, formats etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evernote doesn't force you to be locked in. You can export all your notes as plain text or HTML.

Comment: you're absolutely right.  evernote portable might be the way to go..

Comment: Except that it's not opensource as questioned.

Comment: @zsolt - read it again, i didn't limit the question to only open source tools.

Comment: But then you're locked into HTML. :D

Comment: I would love to have a symbian version of evernote...

Answer (score 23):

Pen and paper.

Comment: Open source hardware and software.

Comment: Besides pen and paper locks you into the physical reality

Comment: Pretty old-school. :-) Organizing paper is a hassle though.

Comment: You can put all your notes on google calendar later...

Comment: Oh snap! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229762/what-single-software-development-tool-do-you-think-holds-the-most-value#229774

Comment: I've tried several different ways to organise my notes. I've tried OneNote, I've tried index cards, I've tried sticky notes, I've tried Notepad.

In the end I always come back to an A4 lined pad and a fine-point gel pen.

Answer (score 12):

Try the one file [tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) for which you can get even shared hosting [here.](http://tiddlyspot.com/)

Comment: A wiki is probably the best suggestion. Allows more structure beyond a simple text file and cross-linking content/topics, etc..

Answer (score 5):

Use a text editor and save as a text file. Guaranteed no lock-in whatsoever.

Comment: I use WinKey to add windows keyboard shortcut that brings up vim with a "notes" file.

Answer (score 4):

The open source [xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) is what I use.  It also lets you annotates PDF files, by using them as a background instead of the more normal blank, lined, or gridded.  Very similar is [gournal](http://www.adebenham.com/gournal/)

There are also the java apps in the same space: [jarnal](http://www.dklevine.com/general/software/tc1000/jarnal.htm) and [notelab](http://java-notelab.sourceforge.net/)

Try the ones that work on your platform and see which you like.  I don't believe any do handwriting recognition, which is a shame, but they all seem to be pretty usable.

Comment: +1 for Xournal if you own a tablet which runs Linux

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.vimoutliner.org/
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=861 (Vim Wiki)
- http://skawina.eu.org/mikolaj/vst.html (Vim ReStructuredText)

(Or another personal Wiki system with vim, just google it).

Plain text all the way...

Comment: Surely this is "vim lock-in" ? :)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm sure emacs has a vim emulator.

Comment: And as these are just plain text files...

Answer (score 2):

[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) mind mapping editor

Answer (score 1):

It might help a little bit if you elaborated a little on what features you want from a note-taking tool.

Emacs with outline-mode is one option.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not exactly a note taking tool, I create my notes using OpenOffice and save them in my [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) folder so that they're available on every pc I log into. It then syncs those notes onto every PC you have it set up on.

Alternately, you can use Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Notepad for quick stuff. From [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260563):

> To create a log file in Notepad:
>   1.    Click Start, point to Programs, point to Accessories, and then click Notepad.
>   2.    Type .LOG on the first line, and then press ENTER to move to the next line.
>   3.    On the File menu, click Save As, type a descriptive name for your file in the File > name box, and then click OK. When you next open the file, note that the date and time 
>   have been appended to the end of the log, immediately preceding the place where new text > can be added. You can use this functionality to automatically add the current date and 
>   time to each log entry.

It's simple, but only works with Windows > 2k.
You should also check out [What do you use to keep notes as a developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer).

Answer (score 1):

Pen and a nice [Moleskine Notebook](http://www.moleskineus.com/moleskine-soft-large-ruled.html)

Answer (score 0):

Notepad and/or VI

Comment: and/or emacs if that's your preference. I've tried both vi and emacs. I used to be an emacs guy, but I'm moving (slowly) to the vi camp. Eventually, I hope to settle in the middle and get somewhat familiar with both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I should reconsider Evernote. As it has a public API it's not that much of a walled garden and I wooudn't mind the "locked to vendor" thingie :)
[Evernote API](http://evernote.com/about/developer/api/)

Comment: I love evernote. But you have to pay them if you exceed their bandwidth limits.

Comment: Something less featured, but forever free would be nice.

Comment: Also, it requires that you upload notes to their server.  Which might be a problem with notes for work.

Answer (score 0):

One more vote here for Vim.

It is open source, available for multiple platforms and there is no lock-in, because the files are accessible with other text editors (except when encrypting with the built-in mechanism, but that would be deliberate lock-in).

Drawbacks:
It might have some slight disadvantage in ease of use and is not really able do handle filetypes other than text.

Answer (score 0):

"[TodoPaper](http://widefido.com/products/todopaper/) is a simple, lightweight, and easy to use to-do list application for Windows." plus it's based on plain txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a mix of a spreadsheet program (export to csv in event of lock-in fear) and a plain text editor, with one file per project, or a folder for projects with more notes.  I usually use a sheet of paper as quick notes, but always commit all notes to disk before allowing more than a full-single sided sheet of paper to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

I build one based on python and html editor, it works well for me, you can get it from github: [MyNote](https://github.com/fiefdx/MyNote), it loos like:
[image]